# jQuery: $.ajax post response with dataType:'json' doesn't launch success callback?

Tags: jquery

Unfortunately I can't post link here to which post request is made to. But i have checked it.

It returns 4 whitespaces. It's not valid json response? That's why it gets canceled and success callback it not processed? Or it's because an error in eval happened and it's not been catched?

It's a bug or normal behavior?

I had to remove dataType and use eval instead with whitespaces removal.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm not understanding.  Can you post a jsfiddle?  Some pseudocode? Something?

Maybe you need to watch the "complete" callback if you don't really care about the response being valid.

Comment: The response which you are getting from server may not be valid. Try to send a valid response for testing it should work fine.

Comment: It works with proper json response. But it's not if response is empty, but with whitespace, one or more \w Shouldn't it trigger success on 200 code or it requires empty json?

Comment: It'll trigger complete, but not success. The response is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your contant has to be (at least)

```
[]
```

try it

Comment: Yea it seems response should be at least an empty array. Like that echo '[]' to use dataType:'json'. Because it expect json to be there instead. How dumb of me. :D Guess time to rest now.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in an `error(e,f,g)` callback. An explanation of why your ajax query is failing should be in `g.message`.